# @Column doesn't work with @ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a table with two columns in case `@ElementCollection` has been used.
I'd like to rename these columns. I can do this for `col1` via `@CollectionTable(joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="login_id"))` but how to rename a `col2`?
This case doesn't work:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="login_id")
)
@Column(name = "profile_id")
public Set<Profile> getDefaultProfiles() {
    return defaultProfiles;
}
```

The name of `col2` stay `defaultProfiles_id`.

I use *Hibernate 4.3.4.Final*

Comment: What is `Profile`? If it's an entity, why do you use `@ElementCollection` to refer to it?

Comment: You mean I should use `@OneToMany` instead?

Comment: Yes, `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany`, depending on what you need.

Comment: OK. Looks like `@Column` works fine with `@ElementCollection` for basic data types only, for example `Set<String>`

Comment: it works for a Map too

Answer (score 0):

A fully working example using a map:

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name="name")
@Column(name="value")
@CollectionTable(name="example_attributes", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="example_id"))
private Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
```

And a fully working example with a list:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Column(name = "attribute")
@CollectionTable(name = "entity_attributes", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id"))
private List<String> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
```